# Accessing GMail using AE.Net.Mail in C#

Tags: c#, gmail, imap

I have implemented the following sample code to access gmail and get the first 10 mail subjects using AE.Net.Mail.

I wonder what is exactly going wrong, I am repeatedly getting the error

> *A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond
>   173.194.79.108:993*

This is the code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
using AE.Net.Mail;
using AE.Net.Mail.Imap;
using System.Configuration;

namespace IMAP
{
    class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            var items = ReadMail();
            if (items != null && items.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var item in items.Take(10))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item.Subject);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        public static List<MailMessage> ReadMail()
        {
            List<MailMessage> messages = null;
            try
            {
                string userName = "yourname@gmail.com"; // Replace with your actual gmail id
                string passWord = "password"; // Replace with your password

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(passWord))
                {
                    using (var imapClient = 
                        new ImapClient("imap.gmail.com", userName, passWord,     ImapClient.AuthMethods.Login, 993, true))
                    {
                        imapClient.SelectMailbox("INBOX");
                        messages = new List<MailMessage>(imapClient.GetMessageCount());
                        messages = imapClient.GetMessages(0, 100, false, true).ToList();
                        imapClient.Disconnect();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Username or Password is empty!");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            return messages;
        }
    }
}
```

Please update me if any one faced a similar issue like this, and how resolved it.

Thanks,
Sriram

Comment: Just a little tip: you are creating a list<mailmessage> and then in the next line you discard it and create a new one with .ToList(); If you wanted to add to the list you created you must use AddRange(...). In your case you create 2 lists of which you only use the second one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume the error you're getting is from the exception thrown from the `ImapClient` constructor which tries to connect to the remote IMAP server. That error is [Winsock error 10060 (Connection timed out.)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which usually happens if your connect packets are blocked or if you try to connect to a wrong host or to a wrong port. You have couple of options here:

- ping/traceroute `imap.gmail.com` and see if it's reachable
- 993 is IMAP SSL port so you can use `openssl s_client -connect imap.gmail.com:993` to check whether you can connect to IMAP server. If you get connected, you'll be presented with gmail's IMAP server certificate and with message `* OK Gimap ready for requests` after which you can type IMAP login command `0 LOGIN username pass`.
- check your proxy settings. Try to connect without using proxies.
- check your router/firewall setting. Is port `993` open?
- try using `imap.googlemail.com` instead of `imap.gmail.com`

Comment: Thank you so much Bojan! I will try all the points you mentioned! And will update you once I make it..

Comment: It worked in my home notebook. It is how ever not working in our work environment. As you said, the port 993 is not opened. Thanks for your input!